# ng-click in a loop is always clicked - ionic 2

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic2

I have a google map in my view and in this map I have many marker and each marker should have a content which contains an a href for more details

This is my code for adding one marker which is used in a loop on all the events saved in the database :

```
setMarker(event){
        let coords = event.location.split(",");
        let location = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[0],coords[1]);
        let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: this.map,
            position: location
        });

        let content = "<h1>" + event.name + "</h1></br><a ng-click="+this.viewEventDetails(event)+"> More Details</a>";
        let infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: content
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', () => {
            infoWindow.open(this.map, marker);
        });

        return marker;
    }
```

and this is my viewEventDetails function :

```
viewEventDetails(event){
        this.navCtrl.push(EventDetailsPage, event);
    }
```

When I load the map view it loads the viewEventDetails on all events , what should I do please ?

Answer (score 1):

Could you change `"</h1></br><a ng-click="+this.viewEventDetails(event)+"> More Details</a>"` to `"</h1></br><a ng-click=\"viewEventDetails(event)\"> More Details</a>"`. I think this should work.

Btw I think `ng-click` should also be substitude with `(click)` since ionic 2 does the angular2 way and therefore does not accept ng-click.

Comment: applying your changes it doesn't work , it doesn't execute the èviewEventDetails(event)`

Comment: did you also change ng-click to (click)?

Comment: In that case I expect you get an error in console like viewEventDetail is not a function. Is this correct?

Comment: Actually no error messages in the console, even when I click on the `a href` it shows nothing

Comment: In your own code function eventViewDetails(event) is triggered on page load because eventViewDetails(event) tries to contatenate the return value of the function. And when you set it as a string like what I did ask you to do it does not working because I expect google maps and the component has different scopes. If you could share you code in plunker or similar tool I would look further to help you.